# How to build repetitive struct

Tags: go, struct

I have a program which parses yamls file to an objects (structs).
I use the following repo to do it

https://github.com/go-yaml/yaml

for example in the file I have:

```
dependency :
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
```

And I use the following struct for it

```
type Dependency struct {
    Name     string
    Type     string
    CWD      string
    Install  []Install
    //here I have the issue
    Requires   ? 
}

type Install struct {
    Name       string
    Group      string
}
```

Now I have two few issue with a bit complex struct.

This is the entry which could be inside the `Dependency` struct and this is how it look in the yaml file

```
   requires:
       - name: db
       - type: mongo
```

but it also can be

```
requires:
       - name: db
       - name: rst
       - name: test
       - name: test2
```

Since it have multiple name properties how should I got build this struct

In addition I've field in the yaml

`_type-version: "1.0.0"`

when I put it inside struct like following I got error since I use `-`

```
type TypeVer struct{
    _Type-version string
}
```

How to overcome this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The yaml package actually allows you to remap the the name for the properties, you can use this to handle your `_type-version` Property.
And your initial question: Just define `Requires` the same as `Install`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/go-yaml/yaml"
)

type File struct {
    TypeVersion string `yaml:"_type-version"`
    Dependency []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name     string
    Type     string
    CWD      string
    Install  []Install
    Requires []Requires
}

type Install struct {
    Name  string
    Group string
}

type Requires struct {
    Name string
    Type string
}

var data = `
_type-version: "1.0.0"
dependency:
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
    requires:
      - name: db
      - type: mongo
      - name: rst
      - name: test
      - name: test2
`

func main() {
    f := File{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", f)

    d, err := yaml.Marshal(&f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t dump:\n%s\n\n", string(d))
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i'll check it now and close the question. one question, assume that you have struct like `install` which you know that it have 2 const properties like `name` and `group`  but you can have additional key val properties which could change , you can get  any key val properties, how would you define this struct , the idea is to read the yaml file modify some values and write it back to fs. thanks!

Comment: In the case of only modifying specific values and keeping everything else intact you might be better of not using a type and use `map[interface{}]interface{}` instead. Navigating this kind of structure is then a bit more work, but you are prepared for unforeseen properties.

Comment: thanks it will be great if you can add to your answer e.g. how it should look like. thanks for support!

Comment: Hi, see if you can help also here :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47906837/parse-yaml-to-struct-with-dynamic-fields