# Parse yaml to struct with dynamic fields

Tags: go, struct

I use the following code to parse yaml to struct which works okay.
Now let's assume that I have a struct like `install` which I know to have two const `properties` like `Name` and `Group` **but** in addition we can have additional `key val properties` which could change, **you can get any key val properties** (dynamic)

How should I define this struct? the idea is to read the yaml file modify some values and **write it back** (with exact same structure with modified value) to **FS**, **therefore** I don't want to miss some dynamically fields which could be in the some yaml file which need to be modified

package main

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/go-yaml/yaml"
)

type File struct {
    TypeVersion string `yaml:"_type-version"`
    Dependency []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name     string
    Type     string
    CWD      string
    Install  []Install
    Requires []Requires
}

type Install struct {
    Name  string
    Group string
   //Here any key value can be
}

type Requires struct {
    Name string
    Type string
}

var data = `
_type-version: "1.0.0"
dependency:
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
    requires:
      - name: db
      - type: mongo
      - name: rst
      - name: test
      - name: test2
`

func main() {
    f := File{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", f)

    d, err := yaml.Marshal(&f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t dump:\n%s\n\n", string(d))
}
```

Example 
`Install` can be like above and also like this

```
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
         a1:test2
         b1:test2
```

And also

```
   install:
           - name: api
             group: test
             z10:123
             zzz:111
```

And many more fields after `name` and `group`

Comment: Have you looked at [viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper)? Rather than load your YAML data into a struct, you can make generic lookups with `viper.Get()` and type assert the return to whatever you need to. If you need "dynamic" access and don't want to define a struct with every possible key, you may find viper easier to use.

Comment: A map maybe? Just a guess....

Comment: @Volker - thanks, there is option in the docs to `map[interface{}]interface{}`, but not sure how to use it in my context...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map instead of a struct for Install will help to solve the problem.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/go-yaml/yaml"
)

type File struct {
    TypeVersion string `yaml:"_type-version"`
    Dependency  []Dependency
}

type Dependency struct {
    Name     string
    Type     string
    CWD      string
    Install  []Install
    Requires []Requires
}

type Install map[string]string

func (i Install) name() string {
    return i["name"]
}

func (i Install) group() string {
    return i["group"]
}

type Requires struct {
    Name string
    Type string
}

var data = `
_type-version: "1.0.0"
dependency:
  - name: ui
    type: runner
    cwd: /ui
    install:
       - name: api
         group: test
    requires:
      - name: db
      - type: mongo
      - name: rst
      - name: test
      - name: test2
`

func main() {
    f := File{}

    err := yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t:\n%v\n\n", f)

    d, err := yaml.Marshal(&f)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("--- t dump:\n%s\n\n", string(d))
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not exactly what I want, see that `name` and `group` are some kind of const and `a1` `b1` `z10` is some dynamic fields which can be many with diff key fields...can you explain with your answer how would you parse those dyanamic fields ?

Comment: Install is just a map. You can range(loop) through the map or write a get func which accepts a key to look up the map. You can get the dynamic fields with these functions easily.